# How to end a do while loop with a user inputted string?

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        do {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
            String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
            String fullLetter = keyboard.nextLine();
            char letter = fullLetter.charAt(0);
            keyboard.nextLine();

            int amount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
                char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
                if (ch == letter) {
                    amount++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(letter + " appears " + amount + " times in " + sentence);

            System.out.print("Continue? ");
            String decide = keyboard.nextLine();
        } while (decide.equals("yes"));
    }
```

}

I want the user to input either "yes" or "no" at the end of the loop, then I want that input to determine whether or not the program will loop again. As it stands right now, the the last line of my code isn't working. I've looked around and I'm not sure what I should do to fix this.

Comment: What exactly does "code is not working" mean? Do you have an error log?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare your variable `decide` outside the loop and initialize inside:

```
String decide;
do {
    //do something ...
    decide = keyboard.nextLine();
} while (decide.equals("yes"));
```

Comment: This worked, I didn't realize I had to declare it outside. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `keyboard.next()` to read a `String` instead of `keyboard.nextLine()`

`next()` only reads a word, `nextLine()` reads the whole line including Enter so it will never be equal to "yes"

Comment: `nextLine` reads *until* the user hit Enter - `'\n'` is not included in the resulting string

Answer (score 0):

You must declare declare the string describe outside of the do/while loop, otherwise it is a local variable of the do/while loop, and cannot be accessed by the do testing portion. Simply using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String decide;
        do {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
            String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
            String fullLetter = keyboard.nextLine();
            char letter = fullLetter.charAt(0);
            keyboard.nextLine();

            int amount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
                char ch = sentence.charAt(i);
                if (ch == letter) {
                    amount++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(letter + " appears " + amount + " times in "
                    + sentence);

            System.out.print("Continue? ");
            decide = keyboard.nextLine();
        } while (decide.equals("yes"));
    }
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You has to define your variable decide outside of the loop:

```
    String decide = null
    do {
      ....
      decide = keyboard.nextLine();
    } while (decide.equals("yes"));
```

Comment: Don't repost my answer :)

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I haven't repost your anser. I have write my own anser ar same time as you. If you take a closer look, you see the difference.